# How to stream x-ndjson content using Express and parse the streamed data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming

I have a TS library using Node **v19.1.0**. The library has a function that observes streamed server events.

The server provides a `/events` route streaming `'application/x-ndjson'` content which might be an event/ping/... ( sending a ping every x seconds is important to keep the connection alive )

My observe function parses the streamed data and inspects it. If it is a valid event it will pass it to a callback function. The caller also receives an abort function to abort the streaming on demand.

Whenever I run tests locally or via CI I get the following error

> Warning: Test "observes events." generated asynchronous activity after the test ended. This activity created the error "AbortError: The operation was aborted." and would have caused the test to fail, but instead triggered an unhandledRejection event.

I tried to minimize the example code using plain JavaScript

```
const assert = require('assert/strict');
const express = require('express');
const { it } = require('node:test');

it('observes events.', async () => {
    const expectedEvent = { type: 'event', payload: { metadata: { type: 'entity-created', commandId: 'commandId' } } };

    const api = express();
    const server = api
        .use(express.json())
        .post('/events', (request, response) => {
            response.writeHead(200, {
                'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson',
            });

            const line = JSON.stringify(expectedEvent) + '\n';
            response.write(line);
        })
        .listen(3000);

    let stopObserving = () => {
        throw new Error('should never happen');
    };

    const actualEventPayload = await new Promise(async resolve => {
        stopObserving = await observeEvents(async newEvent => {
            resolve(newEvent);
        });
    });

    stopObserving();
    server.closeAllConnections();
    server.close();

    assert.deepEqual(actualEventPayload, expectedEvent.payload);
});

const observeEvents = async function (onReceivedFn) {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/events', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        signal: abortController.signal,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('error handling goes here - request failed');
    }

    Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
        if (!response.body) {
            throw new Error('error handling goes here - missing response body');
        }

        for await (const item of parseStream(response.body, abortController)) {
            switch (item.type) {
                case 'event': {
                    await onReceivedFn(item.payload);

                    break;
                }
                case 'ping':
                    // Intentionally left blank
                    break;
                case 'error':
                    throw new Error('error handling goes here - stream failed');
                default:
                    throw new Error('error handling goes here - should never happen');
            }
        }
    });

    return () => { abortController.abort(); };
};

const parseLine = function () {
    return new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(chunk);

                // ... check if this is a valid line...

                controller.enqueue(data);
            } catch (error) {
                controller.error(error);
            }
        },
    });
};

const splitLines = function () {
    let buffer = '';

    return new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
            buffer += chunk;

            const lines = buffer.split('\n');

            for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                controller.enqueue(lines[i]);
            }

            buffer = lines.at(-1) ?? '';
        },
        flush(controller) {
            if (buffer.length > 0) {
                controller.enqueue(buffer);
            }
        },
    });
};

const parseStream = async function* (stream, abortController) {
    let streamReader;

    try {
        const pipedStream = stream
            .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
            .pipeThrough(splitLines())
            .pipeThrough(parseLine());

        streamReader = pipedStream.getReader();

        while (true) {
            const item = await streamReader.read();

            if (item.done) {
                break;
            }

            yield item.value;
        }
    } finally {
        await streamReader?.cancel();
        abortController.abort();
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, when running `node --test`, the test does not finish. I have to cancel it manually.

The test breaks with these lines

```
const actualEventPayload = await new Promise(async resolve => {
    stopObserving = await observeEvents(async newEvent => {
        resolve(newEvent);
    });
});
```

and I think that's because the Promise never resolves. I thought the stream parsing might have a bug but if you remove all the stream parsing stuff and replace

```
Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
    /* ... */
});
```

with

```
Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
    await onReceivedFn({ metadata: { type: 'entity-created', commandId: 'commandId' }});
});
```

it doesn't work neither. Does someone know what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has nothing to do with your promise not resolving since you never even get to that point.

The problem here is that `observeEvents` is not yet initialized when the test is being run and thus throws a `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'observeEvents' before initialization` error.

To see that for yourself you can add a simple `const it = (name, fn) => fn();` stub to the top of the file and run it without the `--test`.

There are multiple ways to fix this and the simplest one is to move the test function to the bottom of the file.

If you don't want to do that you can also define the `observeEvents` function like this: `async function observeEvents(onReceivedFn) {...}`. This way it will be available immediately.